# Is "What better time..." in this sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

> What better time than one in which nothing makes any sense to revive the ancient dream of knowing everything?

Shouldn't it be:

> What is a time than one in which nothing makes any sense to revive the ancient dream of knowing everything?

Comment: The first sentence seems to be grammatically accurate.

Comment: @VarunNair Is the sentence complete?

Comment: Yes, it is a complete sentence, or rather a '_rhetorical question_' than a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence you quote is not a full sentence—its predicate has been deleted—but this is an acceptable and quite common way of phrasing a (usually rhetorical) question. Here's the basic form:

> Should we do Y now?
>   What better time <s>is there</s>?

In your example, the phrase *than one in which nothing makes any sense* is the complement of the comparative *better*, and the infinitival *to revive the ancient dream of knowing everything* is the complement of *time*:

> What better time <s>is there</s> *than X to do Y*?